# Python: filter column and row according to regex in header

Tags: python, regex, grep

I'm writing a script that can grep the rows and columns from a text file that match a regex. I have an implementation but I'm looking to make it more elegant.

This is my input.tsv:

```
        a       b       c       d
a       2       9       6       1
b       6       4       7       0
c       3       7       2       0
d       5       8       2       2
```

I want to do something like this:

```
$ grep-row-column.py -E "[a|c]" input.tsv
         a       c
a        2       6
c        3       2
```

The solution should be able to stream a file (i.e. not read the entire thing into memory).

This is my solution, which works.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys,re

filename="input.tsv"
regex="[a|c]"

prog=re.compile(".*"+regex+".*")
with open(filename) as tsv:
    #find the appropriate columns in the header that match the regex
    line=tsv.readline()
    header=line.split("\t")
    count=0
    cols=[]
    print(header[0], end='')
    for token in header:
        if prog.match(token):
            #add the column indices to a list for use later
            cols.append(count)
            print("\t",token, end='')
        count+=1
    print()
    #in the rest of the line, find the matching rows and 
    #print the columns that match the indices found above
    while line!="":
        line=tsv.readline()
        if line.strip()=="":
            continue
        tokens=line.split()
        if prog.match(tokens[0]):
            print(tokens[0], end='')
            for col in cols:
                print("\t",tokens[col], end='')
            print()
```

Is there a more 'python' way to do this? I couldn't figure out how to avoid all the for loops and if statements. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I reccommend you to post this in [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). It is the perfect site for questions asking to review code that works.

Comment: This may be good for [codereview.se], as long as **A** the code works and is not incomplete **and B** the code is non-hypothetical

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't know about Code Review. I posted it [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/119774/filter-column-and-row-according-to-regex-in-header). Should I delete this question?